Issue with + (void)load method not being called in Swift Package Manager (SPM) for Objective-C files in multi-target Swift library
I am developing a Swift library that supports both Objective-C and Swift. In order to utilize the +load method for initialization tasks, I have implemented it in an Objective-C file. This approach works perfectly when using CocoaPods. However, when I migrated to Swift Package Manager (SPM) and organized my Objective-C files in a separate target (folder ObjC), I encountered an issue where the +load method is not being called during runtime.
